# GNU c++: how to declare that heap can be swapped out when inactive?

Tags: gnu, swap

My code is built in GNU c++. It's heavily multi-threaded and allocates a fairly large amount of RAM. Problem is, I routinely have a *dozen* of different versions of the code "running" at the same time - the "running" being in quotes because *only one* is actually running at any given time: all the others are *suspended*, with all of their threads suspended.

With that many copies of the code in the RAM, I sometimes run out of memory (with disastrous consequences)... while my page file always stays at a measly 2-3% of use. I would like to make my code *swappable* to the page file, thus keeping space in actual RAM available for other programs as soon as I suspend it... but I have no idea of how to do that in g++.

Any idea how to do that? Many thanks!!

Comment: Which operating system are you using? This is heavily OS-dependent. Can you elaborate on what you mean by suspended? Are you doing something specific to suspend them?

Comment: OS-neutral advice: don't access the memory for ~30 seconds. The OS will notice and do the right thing. Unless you explicitely locked the memory area to be non-swappable.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I'm on Win10Pro-64.

Comment: I'm on Win10Pro-64.
I do a lot of allocations with malloc and new, and only free on the program exit - which may be dozens of hours later. I don't know whther that heap was allocated swappable or not (I guess that's the actual question).
By "suspending" I mean calling Win's native suspend on the threads... followed by resume if I get back to the program and continue the (long) computation.
Was the above info helpful? Many thanks!